# Validation of a random forest

Tags: r, cross-validation, random-forest

I am a complete newbie in this area and I am probably doing something wrong. I am trying to use `randomForest` in `R` for a regression and I am using the `iris` dataset. I want predict the `Sepal.Length` from the `Petal.Width` and the `Sepal.Length`. I want to test it with cross validation and I got confused. Here is my example.

```
data <- iris
k = 5
n=floor(nrow(iris)/k)
error=rep(NA,k)

for (i in 1:k){
  s1=((i-1)*n+1)
  s2=(n*i)
  sub=s1:s2
  train=iris[-sub,]
  test=iris[sub,]
  model=randomForest(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Petal.Length,data=train,mtry=1,ntree=501,importance=TRUE)
  prediction=predict(model,newdata=test[,-1])
  error[i]= roc.area(test[,1],prediction)
}
```

Questions

1. Is the ROC a good choice for a regression model?
2. How can I get the accuracies for every fold and for the entire model?

Comment: Did you mean "... from the Sepal.Width and the **Petal**.Length**"? Even with that correction, the premise is faulty - there is no dependence between what you have chosen as features and the prediction target.

Comment: @Bobev I know that. This is just an example of data frame. I just cannot understand how to extract results from folds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the ROC a good choice for a regression model?

AuROC is not a suitable figure of merit for regression models. A better typical choice would be e.g. mean squared error, in your case `sqrt (mean ((test$Sepal.Length - prediction)^2))`

> How can I get the accuracies for every fold and for the entire model?

Your `error[i]= error (test$Sepal.Length, prediction)` is one possibility. I usually prefer to store the predicitions rather than the surrogate models' performance as that allows to look at different figures of merit afterwards, allowing better insight.

If you store the error, you need to take into account that in general test sample size can vary a bit across folds and you need to take care to properly average them ($\sqrt a + \sqrt b \neq \sqrt{a + b}$) - which depends on the figure of merit you decided to use.

Comment: Thank you, your response helped me a lot, especially your comment about the storage of error and the variation of test sample size. Thank you.